# Overriding onCreateOptionsMenu from baseActivity class

Tags: java, android

I have a main class called `BaseActivity` which has a method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Now i extend this class like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

      @Override
      public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
        Log.d("Its called", "Kevin");
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.othermenu, menu);
      }       

}
```

How would i override this method here, should it be a `boolean` or `void`.

**Update:**

```
public class FragmentClass extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

      // How would i over-ride the onCreateOptionsMenu() here of BaseActivity.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any overriding method needs to have the same signature as the method it is overriding. Don't forget to call super, like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
        if( super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu ) ) {
            Log.d("Its called", "Kevin");
            getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.othermenu, menu);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
      }       

}
```

Comment: But my BaseActivity class does not have MenuInflater menuInflater

Comment: Will it be the same when i over-ride it in my fragment class too... i get an error when i try to put this in my Fragment class.

Comment: Of course, the Fragment class has a different signature for onCreateOptionsMenu -- but you can't extend an Activity to get a Fragment anyway.